# SQL Server how to rename a column in a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

```
SELECT 
    CONTACTPHONE1 AS CONTACTPHONE1Orin,
    CONTACTPHONE2 AS CONTACTPHONE2Orin,
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE(UPPER(CONTACTPHONE1), '()-.,/+', '       '), ' ', '') AS CONTACTPHONE1,
    REPLACE(TRANSLATE(UPPER(CONTACTPHONE2), '()-.,/+', '       '), ' ', '') AS CONTACTPHONE2
INTO 
    [dbo].[gz_temp] 
FROM 
    Auct_ABSENTEEBID

SELECT 
    CONTACTPHONE1Orin,
    CONTACTPHONE2Orin,
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(CONTACTPHONE1, 1)) = 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING([CONTACTPHONE1], 1 , LEN([CONTACTPHONE1]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE([CONTACTPHONE1]))) 
            ELSE CONTACTPHONE1
        END AS CONTACTPHONE1,
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(CONTACTPHONE2, 1)) = 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING([CONTACTPHONE2], 1 , LEN([CONTACTPHONE2]) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE([CONTACTPHONE2]))) 
            ELSE CONTACTPHONE2
        END AS CONTACTPHONE2
INTO 
    [dbo].[Auct_ABSENTEEBID_Phone_Cleaning]
FROM 
    [dbo].[gz_temp]
```

The question title may not be clear. What I want to do is to merge these two select statements together. The problem is when I substitute `CONTACTPHONE1` with `REPLACE(TRANSLATE(UPPER(CONTACTPHONE1), '()-.,/+', '       '), ' ', '')` in the second select statement, it becomes super tedious. Is it possible to alias it so that I don't have to use two select statements?

```
SELECT @@Version

Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15669.0 Jul 14 2022 22:09:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `gz_temp`? Why aren't you using a table-variable or even a `#temporary` table?

Comment: I would think you could use a cte instead of this persistent gz_temp table. Other than that I don't really understand what you are asking here.

Comment: Yes it is tedious, and doing it in 2 steps like you're doing is helpful to make it more readable. However I wouldnt be using actual tables to do it.  You can declare the first step with a CTE like,  WITH step1 AS ( query ),  step2 AS (select more from step1) SELECT * FROM step2

Comment: @The Impaler I think so. When I can apply the `REPLACE` logic to the second query, the first query can be removed also.

Comment: @Sean Lange Thanks. Let me check what CTE is.

Comment: Here is the [cte documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Just to be clear, though, `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse` is not `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function with one input parameter, CONTACTPHONE, with one return statement:

```
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(UPPER(CONTACTPHONE), '()-.,/+', '       '), ' ', '')
```

Then, call the function like this functionName(CONTACTPHONE1) and functionName(CONTACTPHONE2) directly in your second query, instead of CONTACTPHONE1 and CONTACTPHONE2 respectively.